# Weighting Different Color Channels in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab

I'm trying to combine the channels of a color image in such a way that each channel is weighted by a certain percentage. E.g. I want 40% of the red channel, 40% of the green, and 20% of the blue. I'm currently using the following code:

```
B(:,:,1) = uint8(double(r) * 0.4);
B(:,:,2) = uint8(double(g) * 0.4);
B(:,:,3) = uint8(double(b) * 0.2);
```

where `B` is the output image. Is this the most efficient method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to cast `r` as a double just to multiply with another double and then recast the result as a `uint8`. You can simply multiply `r` (a `uint8`) by the double and the result will be cast to a `uint8` automatically.

For example:

```
D = uint8(1) * 1.5;
D = 
    2

class(D)
    uint8

isSame = isequal(D, uint8(double(1) * 1.5))
    1
```

So for your example, you can simplify it to the following:

```
B(:,:,1) = r * 0.4;
B(:,:,2) = g * 0.4;
B(:,:,3) = b * 0.2;
```

As far as conciseness you could do:

```
B = cat(3, r * 0.4, g * 0.4, b * 0.2);
```

Or if you don't have to break up `r`, `g`, and `b` for other reasons, multiply the entire `rgb` image at once.

```
B = bsxfun(@mtimes, rgb, reshape([0.4 0.4 0.2], [1 1 3]));
```

Comment: I was just answering my own when you posted. I found that the simplest for me without using technical expressions I was unfamiliar with was: `B(:,:,1) = B(:,:,1) * 0.4;` etc.